# Is there a way to include spaces in my argument?

Tags: python, discord.py

In my discord bot, I have 2 commands do give and create roles. They work perfectly fine, but if the role name includes a space, I have an issue. It counts the second word toward the second argument, making the command produce an error.

```py
# Giverole
@client.command(name='giverole',
                aliases=['gr'],
                brief='Assgins role to a user',
                pass_ctx=True)
async def giverole(ctx, rname, *, member: discord.Member):
    role = get(member.guild.roles, name=rname)
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f'Role added to user {member.mention}')
    print('Giverole command executed\n- - -')

# Createrole

@client.command(name='createrole',
                brief='Creates a role',
                aliases=['cr','makerole'],
                pass_ctx=True)
async def createrole(ctx, rname: str, clr: discord.Colour):
    if ctx.author.guild_permissions.manage_roles:
        await ctx.guild.create_role(name=rname, colour=clr)
        await ctx.send('Role created with name: ' + rname)
        print('Createrole command executed\n-  -  -')
    else:
        await ctx.send('You lack permission.')
    print('Createrole command executed\n-  -  -')
```

Ideally, I should be able to do something like `k!giverole Bot Tester @user`, but instead I get an "Invalid user" error. Is there any way for me to support spaces in the role name? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. Use a role converter and require the role to be mentioned:

   ```
   async def giverole(ctx, role: discord.Role, member: discord.Member):
   ```
2. Require the role to be wrapped in quotes:

   ```
   k!giverole "Bot Tester" @user
   ```
3. Switch the positions of the two arguments so that the converted user comes first, and the potentially spaced name comes as the keyword-only argument.

   ```
   async def giverole(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, rname):
   ```

I would recommend the first option, but you may want to try the others as well to see which one you prefer.

Comment: I opted for the 3rd option, as not all of my roles are mention-able. Thanks for the help!