# Is there a way to Direct Message someone on Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've done some research and found a (maybe) old method for direct messaging someone.

```
async def dm(ctx, recipient=None, message=None):
    if message == None or recipient == None:
        await ctx.channel.send("***Error: Incorrect Usage***\nUsage: `/test [recipient] [message]`")
    else:
        pass

    if message is not None:
        if recipient is not None:
        
            message = str(message)
            await client.send_message(recipient, message)
```

What this code is supposed to do is to get the recipient of the dm and the message, and direct message the person (the `if message == None or recipient == None` is to check for missing arguments, and sending an error message.)
What is the correct/recent way to direct message someone?

Answer (score 2):

A few things to note, if you are comparing with a `None`, instead of a comparison operator (`==`), prefer using an identity operator (`is` or `is not`)

secondly, discord.py by default takes all arguments in a function as string, unless you typecast. You can't "send" a message to a string object. You need to `typecast/typehint` it to `discord.Member`

finally, there are some unnecessary `if/else` statements in your code after the first two lines

I will re-write them, feel free to ask anything you don't understand

```
async def dm(ctx, recipient: discord.Member =None, *, message=None):
    if message is None or recipient is None:
        return await ctx.send("***Error: Incorrect Usage***\nUsage: `/test [recipient] [message]`")
    await recipient.send(message)
```

Comment: Clarification: *Python* itself can take any kind of arguments to functions; it's the Discord API (and thus discord.py) that interprets all command arguments as strings by default. All the rest is great, but that remark could confuse newer Python coders.

Comment: Oh, I just realized that this will only send the first word, because it interprets spaces as delimiters between arguments. Instead of `message=None`, `if message is None`, and `recipient.send(message)`, try accepting `*words`, checking `if not words`, and sending `recipient.send(''.join(words))`.

Comment: Ahh yes, sorry about that, I will edit it

Comment: By adding a bare `*` in your edit, you've made `message` a [keyword-only argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301967/bare-asterisk-in-function-arguments), which I don't think will even work with `discord.py`. `*message` would be to catch [*multiple* arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters) (strings/words) as a tuple.

Comment: but in discord.py, `*` is used to collect all arguments intact, without converting them into tuple (when used inside an `async` function with `@commands.command()` decorator), I use it all the time, and so does everyone who uses discord.py lib

kwargs come before the `*` for example

`async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member = None, *, message = None)`

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I guess I'm not familiar with all the custom behaviors this library adds. (That would probably a be a good thing to explain in your answer, though! With a link to the [relevant documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments).)

Comment: And/or maybe also a link to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56006198/is-there-a-way-to-include-spaces-in-my-argument) about spaces in Discord command arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the [Member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=user#discord.Member) object using `target = ctx.guild.get_member(int(recipient))` and then `await target.send(content=message)`

The user you send the message to has to be in a the server that the command was sent in for my answer to work through.